# Calling view via ajax with submit button works, but hitting enter key just displays ajax dictionary

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have a todo list app adds a `Task` object to the database and appends it to the page, it  is working without a problem. However, it only works when I click the submit button, if I hit the enter key, I just see the ajax data in my browser as such:

```
 {"task": {"id": 1, "title": "example task", "completed": false}}
```

and I am curious as to why this is and if there is a way to change this functionality? The tutorial I'm following mentioned that on my form I must use  `<button type="button">` and not `<input type = "submit">` because the ladder will "send the forms data directly to the TaskList view, but we want to use another way of sending requests so we need to disable this behavior." I imagine that is what is happening when I hit the enter key?

Code:

html:

```
<form id = "createTaskForm" method="post" data-url = "{% url 'task_list_url' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
  {% endfor %}
  <button id = "createButton" type="button">Sumbit</button>
 </form>
    
    
<div id = "taskList">
  {% for task in tasks %}
     {{task.title}}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#createButton').click(function() {
    // Get form data
    let serializedData = $('#createTaskForm').serialize();


    // Now pass it to TaskList view
    $.ajax({
      url: $("#createTaskForm").data('url'),
      data: serializedData,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(response) {
        $("#taskList").append(`${response.task.title}`)
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Python specific:
models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

urls.py:

```
path('tasks/', TaskList.as_view(), name = 'task_list_url')
```

views.py:

```
class TaskList(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = TaskForm()
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'task/task_list.html', {'form': form, 'tasks': tasks})

    def post(self, request):
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_task = form.save()
            # send task object as json response, this return value is what is in success: function(response)
            return JsonResponse({'task': model_to_dict(new_task)}, status=200)
        else:
            return redirect('task_list_url')
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your ajax function *`onclick`* which is why it's working when you click on button if you want to call ajax request on enter or on click then you've to use *`onsubmit`*
change your code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#createTaskForm').on("submit", function() {
    // Get form data
    let serializedData = $('#createTaskForm').serialize();


    // Now pass it to TaskList view
    $.ajax({
      url: $("#createTaskForm").data('url'),
      data: serializedData,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(response) {
        $("#taskList").append(`${response.task.title}`)
      }
    })
  });
});
```